# Initialize class member late

Tags: scala

I need to create a class when I don't have the values to initialize it. Later I will assign the value. For example the code below, is it correct?

```
case class MyClass (val a: Int, val b: Int)

val c = MyClass (null, 1)

// later in the code
c.a = 2
```

Comment: Try to think of your code in a different way. Consider not using nulls and not reassigning values for example, what would your code look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case classes are immutable by default so you don't need the `val` in front of your field declarations:

```
// Instead of this
case class MyClass(val a: Int, val b: Int)

// Do this
case class MyClass(a: Int, b: Int)
```

That said, you can't re-assign a field, instead you have to create a new copy of your instance with the new value:

```
// Instead of this
c.a = 2

// Do this
val updatedC = c.copy(a = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign something later it can't be `val`:

```
case class MyClass (var a: Int, val b: Int)

val c = MyClass(0, 1)

// later in the code
c.a = 2
```

Also `Int` is not a reference type, so `null` is not going to work.